# Why is the folder created on the command line not visible by other programs?

Tags: windows, shell, explorer, mkdir

I created a folder on my Desktop within the command line on Windows, by using the command `mkdir`. I also added some files in there by using the command `type nul >> fileName`.

The folder is there, but two blue arrays appear on its top.

I want to open it on my IDE now.
I'm using PHP Storm, and I'm trying to open a file inside the folder, but when I do
`file` > `open file or project` > `Desktop`
the folder is not visible.

For it was on read-only mode, I have also tried to change such a setting, but nothing changed, I don't know whether or not this is relevant as regards to the issue explained above.

Why a folder created within the command line is not visible by some other program, and how can I solve and avoid the issue in the future?

Comment: This question is a topic for Super User, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Maybe you created the folder in the public desktop folder, and you're browsing the user desktop, or vice versa. Note the working directory in the command line.